# c# datatable insert column at position 0

Tags: c#, datatable, insert, position

does anyone know the best way to insert a column in a datatable at position 0?

Comment: sometimes if you are adding column to the datatable after getting the data from db you may need to set it at the begging.

Comment: im pusing the datatable into a bulk insert

Comment: @Stefan, I believe the order of the columns is relevant when using Sql BulkCopy.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can use the following code to add column to Datatable at postion 0:

```
    DataColumn Col   = datatable.Columns.Add("Column Name", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    Col.SetOrdinal(0);// to put the column in position 0;
```

Answer (score 109):

Just to improve Wael's answer and put it on a single line:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Better", typeof(Boolean)).SetOrdinal(0);
```

UPDATE: Note that this works when you don't need to do anything else with the DataColumn. Add() returns the column in question, SetOrdinal() returns nothing.

Comment: single ligne statement aren't alway better. In this case I like it +1

Answer (score 3):

```cs
using System.Data;
...

//Example to define how to do :
DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
dt.Columns.Add("Address");
dt.Columns.Add("City");
               
//  The table structure is:
//ID    FirstName   LastName    Address     City
    
//Now we want to add a PhoneNo column after the LastName column. 
//For this we use the SetOrdinal function, as in:
dt.Columns.Add("PhoneNo").SetOrdinal(3);
    
//3 is the position number and positions start from 0.
    
//Now the table structure will be:
// ID    FirstName   LastName    PhoneNo    Address     City
```