# Is it possible to insert DataRow into a DataTable at index 0?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339880/c-datatable-insert-column-at-position-0) answers how to insert a DataColumn at position 0.  Is there a way to do the same thing with a DataRow?  Or is that impossible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
DataTable table = //...
table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this does it. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.