# Add column to DataTable and move columns to right

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable with 2 columns in it. I would like to insert another column to the start, and move those 2 columns to the right by 1.

```
 DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered, please search before posting a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339880/c-sharp-datatable-insert-column-at-position-0

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I couldn't find it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Something like this>>

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers");

    DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
    workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
    workCol.Unique = true;

    workTable.Columns.Add("CustLName", typeof(String));
    workTable.Columns.Add("CustFName", typeof(String));
    workTable.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(Double));
```

Hope its helpfull.

Comment: Thanks Freelancer! Do you know how I can fill the new column with one same value until it reaches the end of rows of the other existing columns?

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
DataColumn column = dtCurrentTable.Columns.Add("Column Name", typeof(<<The data type of your column>>));
column.SetOrdinal(0);// to put the column in position 0;
```

Comment: Thanks sandeep. Do you know how I can fill in this new column with one same value until it reaches the last row of all the other columns?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Excellent solution Sandeep. +1!  A little more concise way to do the same thing:
myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add("NewColumn"); myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1].SetOrdinal(0);