# Getting info to display properly in datagridview from database in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a weird problem on my hand. I am trying to read an oracle database and using some queries to get info back. I have a datagridview with column names already set at the beginning of the program. Here is an example setup of my datagridview columns

```
Number   Word   Sentence   Paragraph
```

Now i am reading a database and selecting its columns named N S P representing Number Sentence and Paragraph respectively. How can i load the results of the query into a datatable and display the contents under my datagridview so the N contents in the database are displayed under the Number column and nothing under word column etc. I can always query by selecting N, S and P one at a time, but i want to load all the data at once.

THanks

Comment: I cant exactly post my code here. But its just a test i am running that reads a database using oledb and uses an sql query that looks like: command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT N, S, P FROM dFile WHERE N = 1"). THe only way i know how to store the result is using dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader()); but that loads the datatable with the column names and the set order of column like N then S then P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the column names in the SQL by writing

```
SELECT N AS Number, S AS Sentence, ...
```

Comment: Its telling me an error that select statement includes a reserved word. How do you fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this online reserved word checker http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/

Comment: number is reserved... how do i fix the query?

Comment: awesome, now can you selectively fill a datatable instead of just dumping all the result from the query into it?

Comment: Do you mean you only want data from certain columns?

Comment: The datatable only holds info for N S and P but not for W, In the datagridview under form, the order of columns should be N, W, S, P but if i just load all the info in the datatable to the gridview, the W column between N and S will be missing

Comment: Your query doesn't have W in the select, is that the problem?

Comment: w can come from any other source such as an arraylist holding the hard coded values during the program execution

Comment: You can call `table.Columns.Add`, then loop through the rows and set your new column.

Comment: instructions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351557/how-does-one-insert-a-column-into-a-dataset-between-two-existing-columns

Comment: nice! one kinda related question. How can you resize a column header to fit the header name?