# Input array is longer than the column in the table in txt dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

Am new to C# and i want to know how to extract data from txt dataset and put it in c# dataset and perform some calculations with it.

This is how my dataset looks like

```
5.982   0.228   0.237   0.221   0.222   0.527
2.13    0.262   0.273   0.251   0.254   0.427
```

Here is my amateur code:

```
string file = "D://test1.txt";
string tableName = "table";
string delimiter = "\t";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(file);

ds.Tables.Add(tableName);

string AllData = s.ReadToEnd();

foreach (string r in rows)
{
    string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
    ds.Tables[TableName].Rows.Add(items);
}

int MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
Console.Write(MaxRows);
Console.ReadLine();
```

It always shows an error:

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: You have table with 0 columns defined. Define them first.

Comment: i want to access data only in row wise manner. only 1 column enough for me. And i have no idea how to define one column.

Comment: For instance see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351557/how-does-one-insert-a-column-into-a-dataset-between-two-existing-columns

Comment: It looks like this is the second time you posted this question today.  In the future, please edit your question rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some columns to hold the data first. Something like:

```
var tableName = "MyTableName";
DataTable table = ds.Tables.Add(tableName);

table.Columns.Add("firstColumnName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("secondColumnName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("thirdColumnName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("fourthColumnName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("fifthColumnName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("sixthColumnName", typeof(string));
```

As an example of how to add rows to this table:

```
const string dataFilePath = @"d:\public\temp\data.txt";
string[] fileData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFilePath);
var numColumns = table.Columns.Count;

foreach (string dataItem in fileData)
{
    var items = dataItem.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray()).Take(numColumns);
    table.Rows.Add(items);
}
```

Comment: I have added this in the code , but still am getting the same error. 'ds.Tables[TableName].Columns.Add("column1",typeof(string));'

Comment: Well, that is not the code I posted... Where is the upper-case `TableName` defined?

Comment: Updated with a sample for adding rows.